# How to view all running threads on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pthreads

I would like to know how to view all the threads running on the iPhone. I know that there is a command "top -t" for linux systems and Android for that, but it does not work on the iPhone.

PS : I am running on a jailbroken OS, and my application can run as root.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: you want to see it in xcode or you want to know which threads are aunning via code in objective-c?

Comment: The latter. I would like to view all the threads running and display them programatically in a UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the output from:

```
    ps -eM
```

My Linux machine doesn't seem to support `top -t`, so I'm not sure what per-thread data you're expecting. The first few lines of output (from OS X) looks like:

```
    $ ps -eM
    USER             PID   TT   %CPU STAT PRI     STIME     UTIME COMMAND
    root               1   ??    0.0 S    31T   0:22.78   0:12.34 /sbin/launchd
                       1         0.0 S    31T   0:01.97   0:00.27 
                       1         0.0 S    31T  36:19.72   0:00.42 
    root              17   ??    0.0 S    31T   0:10.79   0:15.90 /usr/libexec/kextd
                      17         0.0 S    33T   0:01.14   0:00.26 
    root              18   ??    0.0 S    31T   0:00.46   0:01.33 /usr/libexec/UserEventAgent -l System
                      18         0.0 S    33T   0:01.85   0:00.44 
                      18         0.0 S    31T   0:00.24   0:00.30 
                      18         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
                      18         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
                      18         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
    _mdnsresponder    19   ??    0.0 S    31T   0:05.70   0:02.21 /usr/sbin/mDNSResponder -launchd
                      19         0.0 S    33T   0:01.14   0:00.26 
                      19         0.1 S    31T   0:30.75   0:29.55
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answering.How about viewing the thread ids and names? Is that possible?